# Random div not working in IE

Tags: jquery, random

I have a script for random DIV but do not work in Internet Explorer.

It was a way to make it work in IE?

```
    $('#all .block').each(function () {
        // get current ul
        var $ul = $(this);
        // get array of list items in current ul
        var $liArr = $ul.children('.item');
        // sort array of list items in current ul randomly
        $liArr.sort(function (a, b) {
            // Get a random number between 0 and 10
            var temp = parseInt(Math.random() * 50);
            // Get 1 or 0, whether temp is odd or even
            var isOddOrEven = temp % 2;
            // Get +1 or -1, whether temp greater or smaller than 5
            var isPosOrNeg = temp > 5 ? 1 : -1;
            // Return -1, 0, or +1
            return (isOddOrEven * isPosOrNeg);
        })
        // append list items to ul
        .appendTo($ul);
    });
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/8vtbdpmn/

Comment: "not working" is abs. meaningless.

Comment: You'll need to clarify "not working" as well as other details - what is not working - are you getting an error? Does it crash IE? Which version of IE are you using? Have you tried debugging through it to see what's going wrong? What do you think the problem is?

Comment: this sorting method does not work in IE, it doesnt sort the colored blocks. i think thats what he meant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is a random sorting, then you dont need that wall of code. just use the following line:

```
return (-1 + Math.random() * 2);
```

it will have the exact same effect, return a random float between -1 and 1. the sort function doesnt even require it to be an integer, just a negative/zero/positive.

<kbd>[Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/8vtbdpmn/1/)</kbd> (works in IE11)